# mamba install fails on github actions

Tags: github-actions, conda, mamba

Installing mamba in a GitHub action with `conda install -y -c conda-forge mamba` fails with: `Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.` followed by a long list of conflicts, [see log](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/BXA/actions/runs/6583504722/job/17886646302)

My [workflow file](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/BXA/actions/runs/6583504722/workflow#L166) is quite simple, here is the relevant portion:

```
...
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 60
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7, 3.8, 3.9, '3.10', 3.11, 3]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install system dependencies
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install -y ghostscript

      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          auto-update-conda: false
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          use-only-tar-bz2: true
          #mamba-version: "*"

      - name: Install mamba
        run: conda install -y -c conda-forge mamba
...
```

I am aware I can install mamba with miniconda within setup-miniconda, but [this also failed](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/BXA/actions/runs/5915451830/job/16041739014) with conflicts.

I'd imagine mamba on github-actions is a very common combination, so I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Be aware that the default solver in Conda is now `libmamba` (same that Mamba uses), so there is very little value to using Mamba in the CI. I still prefer it for interactive stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Miniforge

It is [no longer recommended to use Miniconda + Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mamba-installation.html#existing-conda-install-not-recommended), and there is [an incompatibility](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/13041) with installing Mamba into an environment with Miniconda **base**. Instead, [go straight to Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-incubator/setup-miniconda#example-10-miniforge) (which now includes Mamba):

```yaml
  - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
    with:
      auto-update-conda: false
      python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      use-only-tar-bz2: true
      miniforge-version: latest
```

If subsequent steps in the GitHub workflow specifically depend on the `mamba` command being there (e.g., Snakemake), then this makes sense. Otherwise, if you to instantiate an environment, I would strongly recommend using Micromamba instead.

### Use Micromamba (preferred for CI)

Installing a full Conda **base** in CI is usually unnecessary and state-of-the-art for DevOps needing a Conda *environment* is to use Micromamba. This is a minimal static binary that does Conda environment and package management. For GHA's, there is [the `mamba-org/setup-micromamba` action](https://github.com/mamba-org/setup-micromamba).

In this case, one simply defines what is needed in the environment through a YAML, and Micromamba will create it and configure the activations so that subsequent shell processes can use it.